# Solving for $y$, given $y = 0.8(0.78 - 0.15 - 0.15 - x)$ and $x = \frac1y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the below equation:

$$y = 0.8(0.78 - 0.15 - 0.15 - x) \tag1$$

$x$ relates to $y$ by the below:

$$x = \frac1y \tag2$$

This would give:

$$y = 0.8\left(0.78 - 0.15 - 0.15 - \frac1y\right) \tag3$$

But how do I solve for $y$?

Comment: $y$ can't be zero. Multiply throughout by $y$ to get a quadratic eqn. in $y$

Comment: See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align*} y &= 0.8(0.48 - x) \\
xy &= 0.8(0.48x - x^2) \\
1 &= 0.8(0.48x - x^2) \end{align*}$

What was said in the comments basically.